# vertx-jdbc-client3.5.2 postgresql : sql update cause "A result was returned when none was expected"

Tags: vert.x

In vertx-jdbc-client 3.5.0 ,the sql "`DELETE FROM user;INSERT INTO user...` " is ok.After update to vertx-jdbc-cient 3.5.2,the sql is fail with the error:
`io.vertx.core.VertxException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected`.By debugging, I found that the SQL was changed auto to `DELETE FROM user RETURNING *;INSERT INTO user ...`, then `RETURNING *` cause update error.

I find the cause:in vert-jdbc-client 3.5.0.

```
class JDBCConnectionImpl implements SQLConnection {
...
  private SQLOptions options;
```

}

in vert-jdbc-client 3.5.2:

```
class JDBCConnectionImpl implements SQLConnection {
    ...
    private SQLOptions options = new SQLOptions().setAutoGeneratedKeys(true);
}
```

then casue

```
public class Parser {
...
  private static boolean addReturning(StringBuilder nativeSql, SqlCommandType currentCommandType,
      String[] returningColumnNames, boolean isReturningPresent) throws SQLException {
    if (isReturningPresent || returningColumnNames.length == 0) {
      return false;
    }
    if (currentCommandType != SqlCommandType.INSERT
        && currentCommandType != SqlCommandType.UPDATE
        && currentCommandType != SqlCommandType.DELETE) {
      return false;
    }

    nativeSql.append("\nRETURNING ");
...
}
```

Should I modify the SQL code or set up the JDBC client? Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Comment: Can you please file an issue on https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-jdbc-client/issues/new ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for  tsegismont's suggestion.But I just found it's not a issue,because when i code `SQLConnection sqlConnection = ...;
        sqlConnection.setOptions(null);` ,then old sql update is ok.So it's a change,i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it's not a issue,because when i code `SQLConnection sqlConnection = ...; sqlConnection.setOptions(null);` ,then old sql update is ok.So it's a change,i think.